# How to Evaluate model's r-square after inverting from logarithmic

Tags: python, data-transformation, r-squared, logarithm

I stacked with question about inverting the r-square(`r²`) model value after taking `log1p()`.
My baseline LinearRegression model and Random Forest evaluations:

| Model algorithm | RMSE | r² | MAE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Random Forest | 104.0874 | 0.9410 | 38.8811 |
| LinearRegression | 271.7991 | 0.5977 | 164.7908 |

I tried to take `log1p()` on *y* for new LinearRegression model:

```
y_train_log = np.log1p(np.clip(y_train.copy(), 0, None))
y_valid_log = np.log1p(np.clip(y_valid.copy(), 0, None))

regr = linear_model.LinearRegression()
regr.fit(X_train, y_train_log)
predicts = regr.predict(X_valid)
...
```

Results:

| Model algorithm | RMSE | r² | MAE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| LinearRegression after log | 0.866856 | 0.8143277 | 0.684246 |

So I am sure, I need to take `expm1()` on `predicts` and `y_valid_log` and only
them compute **RMSE** and **MAE** in roder to compare it to previous models, so I did it:

| Model algorithm | RMSE | r² | MAE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| LinearRegression after log | 877.3852 | 0.8143277 | 156.3328 |

But what about r-square(`r²`) ? Should I also take `expm1()` and only then scoring  r-square(`r²`) ?

Comment: RMSE and $R^2$ give redundant information. If a model outperforms another model on one of those, it outperforms the other model on both. Contrast this with MAE, where one model may perform better on MAE while another performs better on RMSE. With that in mind, why do you want to compute both?

Comment: I rely on previously learned tutorials and MOOC's where all metrics are compared.
I need advice if I need to invert _y_ with `expm1()` before scoring r-square